# Migrating from web service to cloud service (custom URL)

Tags: web-services, azure

I plan to move from a webservice currently hosted at ws.mydomain.com/Service1 to a cloud service. I saw I can use CNAME to point the domain to the proper cloud service URL but, from what I understood, I'm not sure how I can map different services to ws.mydomain.com/Service1, ws.mydomain.com/Service2

Basically, I'd need to have different webservices pointing to the same subdomain but with a different path. How can I do that? (this way the existing application would continue to work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want to achieve is having multiple web sites/applications in one web role which is part of a cloud service.

I think this link will help you - [Configure a Web Role for Multiple Web Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/gg433110.aspx) - the last chapter ("Partitioning a domain by using virtual applications").

Assuming that you have Service1 and Service2 in the same vs.net solution and they are separate web projects:

- Create your cloud service (having a custom domain - ws.mydomain.com)
- Create a web role with one web application (might not be one of the services). When deployed in the cloud service, this web application will be accesed as the root (ws.mydomain.com)
- In ServiceDefinition.csdef add a new VirtualApplication under the Site element:

  `<Site name="Web">
    <VirtualApplication name="Service1" physicalDirectory="relative-location-to-Service1-proj" />
    <VirtualApplication name="Service2" physicalDirectory="relative-location-to-Service2-proj" />
     …
  </Site>`
- the sites will be callable at ws.mydomain.com/Service1 and ws.mydomain.com/Service2

Cheers.